# objective c int not declared

Tags: objective-c, int

I am creating a very simple calculator. To save the first user inputed `float`, i save it as a string in the addition action as to save it when they click on the addition button. Then later I call upon it again to add it to the second user inputed `float`. However when i call upon it again it gives the error: Use of undefined identifier `num1`. The same thing happens with the operation integer. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (IBAction)addition {

    NSString *number1 = total.text;
      float  num1 = [number1 floatValue];
    int operation = 1;
    total.text = @"";

}

- (IBAction)equal {

    NSString *number2 = total.text;
    float num2 = [number2 floatValue];

    if (operation == 1) {
        int num3 = num1 + num2;


    NSString *znumber1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", num1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `num1` as an "instance variable" so it's accessible by both functions (usually declared within your `@interface` block).

The way you're declaring it only allows for the code within that function's scope to access it.

I would reccomend [reading up on variable scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class) before continuing.

Comment: What's an "interface variable"?

Comment: The variable declared in interface part of a class.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No, those are called "instance variables".

Comment: @H2CO3 Whoops, my fault! Fixed.

Comment: He meant that...even you were knowing... now he changed it to @interface block... again someone will pull his leg :p

Comment: @AnoopVaidya True, but he does have a point... better to edit it than to have it lead to confusion for others down the road.

Answer (score 1):

`num1` is only in the scope of `(IBAction)addition` so you can't use it in `(IBAction)equal`.

Comment: Why we cant use `(IBAction)equal`?

Answer (score 1):

`num1` is not scoped correctly. It is local to `addition`. You want to put in the interface in your .m file of your class. That will give a private variable for your implementation. If you put in your .h file you will expose to the rest of your program.